# Distance to edge of voronoi diagram

Tags: partitions

I have $N$ points in an inner product space $S$ with inner product $<\cdot,\cdot>$.  Construct a Voronoi partition, $V$, of $S$ with those $N$ points, using the metric induced by the $L_2$ norm.  Given a point $x\in S$, compute the distance of $x$ to each of the paritions.  Can something like the law of cosines be used here?

The partitions are convex, so the Hilbert Projection Theorem gurantees that the distance is well defined.  Since the partitions are relatively simple, I suspect that there's an efficient way to find that distance.  Note that for arbitrary inner product spaces, the standard formula for a subspace projection involves a possible infinite sum.  However, in certain circumstances the inner products are easy to compute, for example with a radial basis function projection.

So, how does one compute the distance from a point to the "edges" of a voronoi diagram?

Comment: The "edge" of a Voronoi tessellation for a finite set of points is not well-defined.  Each Voronoi cell is a region of $S$ closer to a point ${\bf p}$ than any other point, and thus cells on the "edge" extend to infinity.

Comment: That's fine. The distance from a point to each partition is still well defined by [projecting orthogonally](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_projection_theorem) onto the partition, then defining the distance to the partition as the distance to the orthogonal projection. I bring up the term "edge", because that point will always lie on what, intuitively, is the "edge" of the partition.

Comment: On cell $C$ of the Voronoi partition is given by $N-1$ linear constraints. Computing the distance from $x$ to that cell means to minimize $|y-x|^2$ subject to the condition $y \in C$. This is a quadratic programming problem, see e.g.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming.
Or am I missing something?

Comment: My problem is that if $C$ has many or infinite dimensions, I cannot just iterate through the space.  "Choosing" an arbitrary $y$ in $C$ is impossible.  However, I am not interested in the actual vector projection, just the distance.

Comment: What prevents you from projecting everything to the (affine) plane generated by your $N$ points and working in $\mathbb R^N$?

Comment: @fedja, not all inner product spaces are euclidean spaces.  This is an interesting idea, though.

Comment: "not all inner product spaces are euclidean spaces" What exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean that my $N$ points may be, just as an example, arbitrary square-integrable functions.  Thus, the space generated by using those $N$ points as a basis is not $R^N$.